# fixed container on the top of scrollable alert dialog

Tags: flutter, dialog

I need to make a content pinned to the top of the scrollable alert dialog. I tried to do it in several ways, but I only managed to make all the content of the dialog scrollable. The first video shows how it is happening today and the second shows more or less what I would like to happen, but with the difference that the fixed part must be on top.

To fix this, I used actions, but actions are always at the bottom of the alert dialog and I really needed it to be at the top. I'll make the videos available to make it easier to solve the problem:

how is (it should be with top fixed informations):

[image]

how is with the informations fixed on bottom using actions:

[image]

the code:

```
AlertDialog(
            scrollable: true,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            ),
            // insetPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            content: Consumer<ShowNsuImageProvider>(
              builder: (BuildContext context, value, Widget? child) {
                return Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 80,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 20),
                              child: Icon(Icons.close, color: Color.fromRGBO(51, 51, 51, 1))
                          )
                      ),
                      
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "Onde encontrar o NSU do equipamento?",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14,
                                fontFamily: "OpenSans",
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(51, 51, 51, 1),
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                              ),
                            ),

                            SizedBox(height: 30),

                            Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Text(
                                "Selecione o modelo do equipamento:",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                    fontFamily: "OpenSans",
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(51, 51, 51, 1),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),

                      Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        for(int i = 0; i < nsuEquipmentImageList.length; i++)
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: i == 0 ? 0 : 15, bottom: 15),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: (){
                                        isEquipmentSelectedToShowNsuImageList[i] = !isEquipmentSelectedToShowNsuImageList[i];
                                        value.setListEquipmentSelectedToShowNsuImage(isEquipmentSelectedToShowNsuImageList);
                                        isEquipmentSelectedToShowNsuImageList = value.getIsEquipmentSelectedListToShowNsuImage;
                                      },
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                            child: Text(
                                              nsuEquipmentImageList[i]["name"],
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 14,
                                                  fontFamily: "OpenSans",
                                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(51, 51, 51, 1)
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Icon(value.getIsEquipmentSelectedListToShowNsuImage[i] ? Icons.keyboard_arrow_up_outlined : Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_outlined , color: Colors.black)
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Visibility(
                                      visible: value.getIsEquipmentSelectedListToShowNsuImage[i],
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: [
                                          SizedBox(height: 20),
                                          Container(
                                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-170,
                                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-130,
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                image: DecorationImage(
                                                    image: AssetImage(nsuEquipmentImageList[i]["image"]),
                                                    fit: BoxFit.cover
                                                ),
                                                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                                            ),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(height: 0.5, color: Colors.black)
                            ],
                          ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20)
                      ],
                        )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }
            ),
          );
```

would someone be able to help me with this?

Comment: What about displaying in `Title` of `AlertDialog`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using `scrollable: true`, it makes contents scrollable, including the `title` as well. Using ListView inside AlertDialog content, create constraints issue. You can use LayoutBuilder on top and provide the constraint based on your need.

```dart
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        final width = constraints.maxWidth;
        final height = constraints.maxHeight;
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Top Part"),
          content: SizedBox(
            width: width,
            height: height,
            child: ListView(
              children: List.generate(
                33,
                (index) => SizedBox(
                  height: 100,
                  child: Text(index.toString()),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Anothers way of doing is using Column on with `SingleChildScrollView`

```dart
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text("Top Part"),
      content: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: List.generate(
            33,
            (index) => SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              child: Text(index.toString()),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: using the `title` for fixed item.

Comment: your answer solved my problem. Thank you so much!! I used the second option, with singlechildscrollview.

Thanks!!

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/constraints)